Indicate to mypy that an attribute cannot be none in a subclass
Given the following code
@dataclass
class MaybeTextContainer:
    text: list[str] | None


class CertainlyText(MaybeTextContainer):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(text=[])
        self.say_hi()

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        self.text.append("Hi")


mypy will complain on the last line that error: Item "None" of "list[str] | None" has no attribute "append". Of course I could add a assert self.text in the say_hi function, but that's ugly if you modify self.text in a lot of functions.
Is there a general way to indicate that self.text cannot be None anymore?

Subclasses cannot be more restrictive than their parents in this case; it's a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. MaybeTextContainer.text should probably just be list[str] in the first place. Do you have a specific distinction between [] and None in mind?

In my case the MaybeTextContainer was a given class in another package so I don't know why it was made that way. Upon serialization using pydantic, using None would omit the field, and using [] it would produce JSON with an empty array. But maybe that is still acceptable.

Why would pydantic omit the field?

@chepner well, this is a specific kind of LSP violation allowed by mypy. You can override subclass attributes to more specific type unless you have mutable-override optional err code enabled.

Simply annotate text as list[str] in the subclass:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MaybeTextContainer:
    text: list[str] | None


class CertainlyText(MaybeTextContainer):
    text: list[str]
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(text=[])
        self.say_hi()

    def say_hi(self) -> None:
        self.text.append("Hi")

This passes type checking with mypy --strict (mypy b1.9.0):
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

Try it yourself on the mypy playground
